# Responsive Bootstrap problems

Tags: android, html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

1. I have some problems on my responsive layout im trying to create. 
   The Home page look like shit on phones and on big ass screens.
2. The music section looks really good on my 13 inch Macbook, but on my iPhone the Apple Music and Spotify buttons, is being pushed down, so it doesn't look good anymore.
3. I wan't to add youtube videos on my music section too. The youtube videos has to be inside the the grey square i have made. I have tried to put it in the div class="container" and div class="jumbotron"
   but it does not work.
   i know this is a bit of a mouthful, but i would really appreciate it.

I have takken a little inspiration by this website
http://www.spotify-thedrop.com/#/

You can take a look at my website here.
http://homeofedm.com/

Here is the coding for my problems.

This is for the Home section

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/david guetta.jpg" /></a>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Meow</h3>
          <p>Just Kitten Around</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/zedd.jpg" /></a>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Meow</h3>
          <p>Just Kitten Around</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/steve aoki.jpg" /></a>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Meow</h3>
          <p>Just Kitten Around</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<a href="avicii.html">
<div class="col-sm-4"> <img id="avicii" src="images/avicii2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</a>
<a href="default.asp">
<div class="col-sm-4"> <img id="martin" src="images/martin garrix.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</a>
<a href="default.asp">
<div class="col-sm-4"> <img id="david" src="images/david guetta2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<a href="default.asp">
<div class="col-sm-4"> <img id="zedd" src="images/zedd2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</a>
<a href="default.asp">
<div class="col-sm-8"> <img id="dim" src="images/dimitri vegas and like mike.png" alt="" /></div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

css.

```
> #avicii {   height: 458px;   width: 458px; }
> 
> #martin {   height: 458px;   width: 458px; }
> 
> #david {   height: 458px;   width: 458px; }
> 
> #zedd {   height: 458px;   width: 458px; }
> 
> .navbar.navbar-inverse {   margin-bottom: 0; }
> 
> #dim {   height: 458px;   width: auto; }
```

Music section

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
<h3>Home (feat. Alex Joseph) - Single<h3>
<img src="images/Home (feat. Alex Joseph) - Single.jpeg" alt="" />
<a id="music" href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/home-feat.-alex-joseph-single/id1081864517?mt=1&app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_music-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/track/12HmJ4Q5ksOGgaqKgZLvdE">
<img id="spotify" src="images/spotify.png" alt="" />
</div>
</a>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
<h3>Aural Psynapse (ATTLAS Remix) - Single<h3>
<img src="images/Aural Psynapse (ATTLAS Remix) - Single.jpeg" alt="" />
<a id="music1" href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/aural-psynapse-attlas-remix/id1065961780?mt=1&app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_music-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/track/1JTMC6LvxZ66NLi25nqitw">
<img id="spotify1" src="images/spotify.png" alt="" />
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
<h3>Parnassia - Single<h3>
<img src="images/Parnassia - Single.jpeg" alt="" />
<a id="music2" href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/parnassia-single/id1076534339?mt=1&app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_music-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/track/0BkLLh1dgbUUof2COoAOWC">
<img id="spotify2" src="images/spotify.png" alt="" />
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
<h3>Lifted - Single<h3>
<img src="images/Lifted - Single.jpeg" alt="" />
<a id="music3" href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/lifted-single/id1071404761?mt=1&app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_music-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/track/2YHsab2zqZ70oQ1H54KmrD">
<img id="spotify3" src="images/spotify.png" alt="" />
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
<h3>Love Is Blind (feat. Glenna) [Remixes] - Single<h3>
<img src="images/Love Is Blind (feat. Glenna) [Remixes] - Single .jpeg" alt="" />
<a id="music4" href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/love-is-blind-feat.-glenna/id1081220187?mt=1&app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_music-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/59hXL8XHJIiyGcOEQrDxCO">
<img id="spotify4" src="images/spotify.png" alt="" />
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
<h3>Get Down (Extended Mix) - Single<h3>
<img src="images/Get Down (Extended Mix) - Single .jpeg" alt="" />
<a id="music5" href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/get-down-extended-mix-single/id1065898774?mt=1&app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_music-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/track/0FZOz3LYpe6d0dKk5g0Ngu">
<img id="spotify5" src="images/spotify.png" alt="" />
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
<h3>Whatever (feat. KOLAJ) [Remixes] - Single<h3>
<img src="images/Whatever (feat. KOLAJ) [Remixes] - Single .jpeg" alt="" />
<a id="music6" href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/whatever-feat.-kolaj-remixes/id1082087582?mt=1&app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_music-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/6wQKF3wXM7LNHREX2GKfsk">
<img id="spotify6" src="images/spotify.png" alt="" />
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

css.

```
#music {
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
}

#spotify {
position: absolute;
  height: 35px;
  width: 110px;
  top: 320px;
}

#music1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 655px;
}

#spotify1 {
position: absolute;
  height: 35px;
  width: 110px;
  top: 695px;
}

#music2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1025px;
  }

  #spotify2 {
  position: absolute;
    height: 35px;
    width: 110px;
    top: 1065px;
  }

  #music3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1400px;
    }

    #spotify3 {
    position: absolute;
      height: 35px;
      width: 110px;
      top: 1440px;
    }

    #music4 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 1770px;
      }

      #spotify4 {
      position: absolute;
        height: 35px;
        width: 110px;
        top: 1810px;
      }

      #music5 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 2140px;
        }

        #spotify5 {
        position: absolute;
          height: 35px;
          width: 110px;
          top: 2180px;
        }

        #music6 {
          position: absolute;
          top: 2515px;
          }

          #spotify6 {
          position: absolute;
            height: 35px;
            width: 110px;
            top: 2555px;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about grid system

**Large devices** Desktops (.col-lg-) which means equal or greater than 1200px.

**Medium devices** Desktops (.col-md-) which means less than 1200px but equal or greater than 992px.

**Small devices** Tablets (.col-sm-) which means less than 992px but equal or greater than 768px.

**Extra small** devices Phones (.col-xs-) which means less than 768px.

You can make different layout in different devices by changing there value.

Also you can use

**.hidden-sm** class to hidden perticular element

**.visible-sm-** to make visible particularly
For more info read bootstrap documentation